# Como Resetar Campos Select2 e Multiselect do Formulário

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

Tenho um formulário de cadastro onde eu reseto os campos ao inserir um registro com o seguinte:

```
document.getElementById(id).reset(); //Aqui passo o id do formulário
```

O problema é que agora tenho um campo [select2](https://select2.github.io/) e um [multiselect](http://loudev.com/) que não estão sendo resetados.

```
<select name="funcao_id" class="form-control select2">
    ...
        <option>...</option>
    ...
</select>

<select multiple id="exames" name="exames[]" class="form-control">
    ...
        <option>...</option>
    ...
</select>

<script>
    $(function () { $(".select2").select2(); });
</script>
```

> Coloquei apenas as partes relevantes do código, caso precise eu ponho algo mais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe para fazer reset do *select2* é `.select2("val", "");`.

Podes usar assim:

```
$('select').select2(); // iniciar o select2
$('form').on('reset', () => { // acionar quando o reset acontecer
  $(this).find('select').select2("val", ""); // fazer reset do select2
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a7gx0yyd/

Answer (score 0):

tenta assim:

```
$('#multiselect').prop('selectedIndex',0);
$('#select2').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

esse código vai deixar selecionado o primeiro item